# In what cases Do I need to implement OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

I want to know what the best scenarios for using OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 has few grant types. We choose one based on client type. Who is your client and IDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some info about thit OAUTH 2 flow here.

> The OAuth 2.0 JWT bearer token flow is similar to a refresh token flow within OAuth. The JWT is posted to the OAuth token endpoint, which in turn processes the JWT and issues an access_token based on prior approval of the app.